# Hide the repeated column values in Angular table based on SQL

Tags: angularjs

How to put blank in repeated cell columns in HTML or Angular ng-grid?

There is the SQL which returns 2 columns:

```
SELECT country, city FROM t ORDER BY country
```

Currently I am using Angular 1.2 and https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid#v2.0.12
to display SQL result in browser:

```
Country   City
-------   ---- 
FRANCE    Paris
FRANCE    Lyon
ITALY     Rome
ITALY     Milan
```

I would like to hide the repeated country name (show it only once). The result should like this:

```
Country   City
-------   ---- 
FRANCE    Paris
          Lyon
ITALY     Rome
          Milan
```

I consider 3 options to achieve this:

1) Make extra work on server-side: instead returning SQL result to front-end do the data massaging to eliminate the duplicate countries in results

2) Learn if angular’s ng-grid has this option embedded

3) Do not use ng-grid and use Angular’s ng-repeat to build HTML table... but still cannot find the way how to remove duplicates

Comment: post your code, what you did so far. Suppose today you able to show all SQL data but face problem to Group by Country, right?

Comment: I do not need to GROUP BY country. I want the exact same # or rows to be displayed, as in original result, just want to hide the repeated countries

Comment: Do you want somethong like this: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping ?

Comment: The example in link above is too heavy for my simple case. I just want to display the empty cell if the value is the same as in cell above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do some manipulation with data and set `show` value as `true/false`. After, you can write some custom cell template:

```
$scope.myData = [
    {
        "country": "FRANCE",
        "city": "Paris",
        "show": true
    },
    {
        "country": "FRANCE",
        "city": "Lyon",
        "show": false
    },
    {
        "country": "ITALY",
        "city": "Rome",
        "show": true
    },
    {
        "country": "ITALY",
        "city": "Milan",
        "show": false
    }
];

var template = '<div class="grid-tooltip">' +
                        '    <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" data-ng-if="row.entity.show">' +
                        '      {{ COL_FIELD }}' +
                        '    </div>' +
                        '  </div>';

$scope.gridOptions = {
  data:$scope.myData,
  columnDefs: [
    {
      name: 'country',
      displayName: 'Country',
      field: 'country',
      cellTemplate: template
    },
     {
      name: 'city',
      displayName: 'City',
      field: 'city'
    }
    ]
  }
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nD1b9HTpHAy9DCq06qN5?p=preview)</kbd>

---

It also will give you flexibility with column sorting